# Gitlab office 365 smtp setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, office365, gitlab

With the incorrect setup I got the following when sending a test email via gitlab-rails console:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown
>   state: unknown protocol

See my answer below with the setup that eventually worked.

Comment: Are you on windows ?

Comment: No, our gitlab is hosted on a redhat server.

Answer (score 3):

The settings in the gitlab config file that worked:

```
### Email Settings
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@yourdomain.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'Gitlab'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'gitlab@yourdomain.com'
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_subject_suffix'] = ''

### GitLab email server settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html
###! **Use smtp instead of sendmail/postfix.**

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.office365.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@yourdomain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "office 365 login password"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "yourdomain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false

###! **Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert'**
###! Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
```